# Does the JVM automatically load agents without specifying agentlib or agentpath

Tags: java, jvm, agent, javaagents

I'm using JBoss (4.2.3) with Java 1.7.0_21 and was loading an agent dll (YourKit yjpagent.dll) via the -agentlib JVM flag. After removing this flag (but not deleting the agent dll) the agent still appears to be loaded.

The dll is in the JBoss bin directory. When the server is running I can't delete the file (as it is locked by the server process) and in hotspot dump files I see the agent in the trace.

I can't find any documentation that says agents will be loaded implicitly, but is this a known feature of the JVM?

I searched the code base for any other reference to the agent but can't find any.

Comment: In general i wonder alot about these agentlib options and the JVM.  This seems to be underdocumented.  Hope this question gets an answer soon.

Comment: After you removed the agentlib JVM flag, did you make sure that the JBoss process was shutdown completely? You can run `<JDK_HOME>\bin\jps.exe -v` to make sure the current Jboss process does not still have the `-agentlib` flag.

Comment: @jayunit100 Here is a documentation from Oracle for [JVMTI Agent Command-Line Options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#starting). And how [VM agents works](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jvm-ti-141370.html).